# "Алгоритмы " Кормен

Tags: алгоритм

У Кормена в его книге "Алгоритмы" приводится анализ кода сортировки вставкой, в частности количество выполнений строки:

```
for j<-2 to length[A]
```

указывается как n, но ведь если идти от двух, то количество выполнений будет равно n-1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В теории алгоритмов это означает не ровно n, а сопоставимо с n. То есть время будет зависеть от этого самого n.
Как пример, часто используются алгоритмы с такими двумя вложенными циклами:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        // ...
```

Количество итераций в данном случае будет

```
(n * (n - 1)) / 2
```

, но на практике такой алгоритм является квадратичным.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/104219/ вот неплохая статья для начинающих